# How to save/reinstall Ubuntu without LiveUSB

Tags: upgrade

Been using Ubuntu for years, consider myself kind of an advanced user, and I assure you I have spent the better half of the day trying things and googling around.

Here's what happened:
Upgraded my 64bit 13.10 to 14.04 this afternoon (upgrade, not a fresh install) on a Lenovo X1 Carbon which had previously worked flawlessly out of the box.

The first restart upon finished installation/upgrade rendered my machine unusable:
- I see no bios/lenovo screen upon powering on the machine
- screen stays blank (HD activity, screen is lit)

What I can do:
- plug a HDMI cord into the machine and use the laptop from my TV. Laptop screen stays blank

What I can't do (and here is where it gets weird):
- I cannot boot a live USB installation. Either because it just doesn't work, or it works but I don't see anything (because of the blank screen). At any rate, even if it works (which I cannot tell), in that option the 2nd screen isn't on.

HOW can I reset/reinstall my complete OS if I cant do a from-USB-installation? Is there a way (scripts, terminal commands etc) to reset all the boot parameters, grub, graphics drivers etc...?

How would I roll back to 13.10? So I am basically running a current daily 14.04

Help is much much apprciated. I am totally frustrated, I have no backup laptop to take to work with

Comment: Reinstalling is the only way.

Comment: The bios is not related to Ubuntu. It starts way before the computer even knows that you have an operating system. Have you tried a hard poweroff? Sometimes the screen can die temporarily and you have to cut off the power for it to start working again. But Ubuntu certainly will never prevent the BIOS from being displayed. That's not possible.

Comment: Not sure what you are suggesting... I cannot hard poweroff.